# Oracle SQL round up time interval to next day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rounding

How to round up time interval to next day in Oracle SQL?

```
select apppackage
       , numtodsinterval(
            sum( trunc(extract (day from (periods)) * 86400
            + extract (hour from (periods)) *3600
            + extract (minute from (periods))*60
            + extract (second from (periods)))
            ), 'SECOND') as retention_period
      , count(apppackage) as users
from retentions 
where apppackage = 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' 
group by apppackage;
```

The output of this is

> 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' '+2969 04:32:47.000000' '3'

and desired output is

> 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' '2970' '3'

but if the output of query is

> 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' '+2969 00:00:00.000000' '3'

then desired output is

> 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' '2969' '3'

column period is of INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(6) type
and i won't mind if the retention_period is changed to number datatype.

I'll be grateful if anyone can suggest change in my query to attain the desired output.

Comment: Is precision meaningful in your real-life problem? I ask because `TRUNC` is applied in the wrong place. You should compute the sum, and only then apply `TRUNC` to seconds (and, in fact, you should round up... or not even apply `TRUNC` to seconds at all, if you will use Alex Poole's answer). To understand the issue, you are doing something like TRUNC(1.9) + TRUNC(1.9) to get 2, when in fact you should do 1.9 + 1.9 = 3.8 and then round either down or up as needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @mathguy... I probably don't need TRUNC in my actual query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your sum is in seconds, so you don't really need to convert it to an interval at all. Just divide by 60*60*24 to get the answer in days, and round it up with `ceil()`:

```
select apppackage
       , ceil(sum( trunc(extract (day from (periods)) * 86400
            + extract (hour from (periods)) *3600
            + extract (minute from (periods))*60
            + extract (second from (periods)))
            ) / 86400) as retention_period
      , count(apppackage) as users
from retentions 
where apppackage = 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' 
group by apppackage;
```

Demo with artificial data in a CTE just to mimic your expected results, for both scenarios:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with retentions (apppackage, periods) as (
  select 'com.Freesoul.Rotter', interval '+2967 04:32:47.000000' day(9) to second(6) from dual
  union all
  select 'com.Freesoul.Rotter', interval '1' day from dual
  union all
  select 'com.Freesoul.Rotter', interval '1' day from dual
  union all
  select 'com.Freesoul.XYZ', interval '+2967 00:00:00.000000' day(9) to second(6) from dual
  union all
  select 'com.Freesoul.XYZ', interval '1' day from dual
  union all
  select 'com.Freesoul.XYZ', interval '1' day from dual
)
-- actual query
select apppackage
       , ceil(sum( trunc(extract (day from (periods)) * 86400
            + extract (hour from (periods)) *3600
            + extract (minute from (periods))*60
            + extract (second from (periods)))
            ) / 86400) as retention_period
      , count(apppackage) as users
from retentions 
where apppackage = 'com.Freesoul.Rotter' 
-- extra clause for dummy data
or apppackage = 'com.Freesoul.XYZ'
group by apppackage;

APPPACKAGE          RETENTION_PERIOD      USERS
------------------- ---------------- ----------
com.Freesoul.XYZ                2969          3
com.Freesoul.Rotter             2970          3
```

Your expected output shows a plain number. If you actually want it as an interval, but as the whole number of days, just pass ceil'd number into `numtodsinterval` or more simply (and usually faster for some reason) multiply by `interval '1' day`.

With the same dummy data:

```
select apppackage
       , ceil(sum( trunc(extract (day from (periods)) * 86400
            + extract (hour from (periods)) *3600
            + extract (minute from (periods))*60
            + extract (second from (periods)))
            ) / 86400) * interval '1' day as retention_period
      , count(apppackage) as users
...

APPPACKAGE          RETENTION_PERIOD           USERS
------------------- --------------------- ----------
com.Freesoul.XYZ    +2969 00:00:00.000000          3
com.Freesoul.Rotter +2970 00:00:00.000000          3
```

As @mathguy pointed out, you probably don't need or want the `trunc()` call in there; that is removing the fractional seconds from each period before they are summed, which sounds insignificant but could easily affect the result you get.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
CASE WHEN numtodsinterval(extract (day from periods), 'DAY') = periods THEN 
    extract (day from periods)
ELSE
    extract (day from periods) + 1
END
```